# Using a Class Type as function input parameter without initializing it

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a class which conforms to a certain protocol.

```
    protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}


class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() { }

}
```

In another class I have a function which has input parameter of **MyProtocol**.

```
func customFunction(with: MyProtocol) { }
```

When I call this function with input parameter **MyClass** (which actually conforms to **MyProtocol**), I get an error saying *MyClass does not conform to MyProtocol*

```
customFunction(with: MyClass)
```

I know I should actually use an instance of **MyClass**, but I just need the type of **MyClass**. Is there a workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function to take the type rather than an instance of the type as an argument

```
func customFunction(with type: MyProtocol.Type) {}
```

Then you can call it with a type conforming to the protocol

```
customFunction(with: MyClass.self)
```